# Python 3.11.4 launcher.wixproj cannot detect v143 buildtools

Tags: python, wix, visual-studio-2022, cpython

I tried to build Python 3.11.4 with Visual Studio 2022 (v143) and I get following error at the end of compilation.
Rest of the project binaries are built using v143 successfully.

I used following command to build: **Python\Tools\msi\build.bat" -x64 --pack**

<sub>Project "D:\build\DE-Python\Python\Tools\msi\launcher\launcher.wixproj" (1) is building "D:\build\DE-Python\Python\PCbuild\pyshellext.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(456,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v143 (Platform Toolset = 'v143') cannot be found. To build using the v143 bui
ld tools, please install v143 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [D:\build\DE-Python\Python

PCbuild\pyshellext.vcxproj]</sub>

**My system details:**

```
VCIDEInstallDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC
VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC
VCToolsInstallDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532
VCToolsRedistDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.36.32532
VCToolsVersion=14.36.32532
VisualStudioVersion=17.0
VS170COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools
VS2022INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional
```

Comment: I tried to build Python 3.10.12 code on same setup and it builds fine and creates local installer under D:\Python_3_10_12\Python-3.10.12\PCbuild\amd64\en-us on my setup.

This issue I can see on 3.11.1 also, what is changed in 3.11.x series?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Python 3.11.x and 3.12.x series and I have logged defect for this on GitHub for cpython: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/106765

Developers can no longer create windows installer using VisualStudio 2022(v143 BuildTools) for python 3.11+ from c-source